Rotating a vector and quaternion between two vectors
Recently when I code quaternion functions, I found one problem with quaternion.
If I rotate vector x by quaternion q to obtain vector y, then calculate the quaternion between x and y. I obtained something that is different than q.
Here is my code, if you would like to try:
import numpy as np

def qrot(q, v):
    original_shape = v.shape
    q = q.reshape(-1, 4)
    v = v.reshape(-1, 3)
    qvec = q[:, 1:]  # The vector part (x, y, z)
    w = q[:, :1]  # The scalar part (w)
    uv = np.cross(qvec, v, axis=1)
    uuv = np.cross(qvec, uv, axis=1)
    rotated_v = v + 2 * (w * uv + uuv)
    return rotated_v.reshape(original_shape)

def qbetween(v0, v1):
    v = np.cross(v0, v1)
    w = np.sqrt((v0 ** 2).sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True) * (v1 ** 2).sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)) + (v0 * v1).sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    q = np.concatenate([w, v], axis=-1)
    q /= np.linalg.norm(q, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    return q

np.random.seed(10)
x = np.random.rand(3)
x /= np.linalg.norm(x)


q = np.array([0.26925564, 0.03266701, 0.4271086, -0.8625616])
q /= np.linalg.norm(q)
y = qrot(q, x)

q1 = qbetween(x, y)
q1 /= np.linalg.norm(q1)
print(q)
print(q1)

y1 = qrot(q1, x)
print(y)
print(y1)


There are infinitely many rotations (and hence quaternions) that rotate $x$ to $y$. Not only that, but for each rotation there are two unit quaternions which represent it. Your qbetween (supposedly) calculates the unit quaternion with positive scalar part representing the rotation about the $x\times y$ axis that takes $x$ to $y$. I say "supposedly" because the calculation looks incorrect to me.
